# .htaccess Redirect With Query String in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all urls in my WordPress site from something like `https://domain.com/view-image/?id=349` to new url `https://domain.com/?p=349`.

I've tried using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^view-image/$ /?p= [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, just add %1 variable to your rewrite destination

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^view-image/$ /?p=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

This what my .htaccess looks like this https://gist.github.com/427a05825dd342ce3e96814eef86c41a

Comment: Is **view-image/** an existent directory?

Comment: No, it's not an actual directory.